# UI automation not tracking Telerik controls

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am creating an application which will record the all the application level and control events . I am using the White recorder framework, it is able to trace the other controls which are not telerik based . I want to know why the telerik controls are not getting traced since it is derived from System.Windows.Control class .

Is there any way we can use UI automation elements to track all Telerik controls . How could we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Windows Forms does not support UIA while Silverlight and WPF does. Here are a few links about this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsautotest/thread/016e46e3-f7cd-46fb-9e12-728f4c846304
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lixiong/archive/2009/03/28/msaa-uia-brief-explanation.aspx